# uninitialized int error code in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with an assignment that asks me to write a program that gets the user name, 10 separate numeric grades, then return those number grades, as well as the letter grade equivalents, numberic average and letter average to the user.  I am getting error C4700, uninitialized local variable.  Any tips on where I went wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main (){

    //Define all variables for grades, average, username, and letter grades.

    int grade1,
        grade2,
        grade3,
        grade4,
        grade5,
        grade6,
        grade7,
        grade8,
        grade9,
        grade10;

    double average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5 + grade6 + grade7 + grade8 + grade9 + grade10) / 10;

    string username;

    string letter1,
           letter2,
           letter3,
           letter4,
           letter5,
           letter6,
           letter7,
           letter8,
           letter9,
           letter10,
           letteravg;

    //Define definitions for letter grades for comparison
    const int A_Score = 90,
              B_Score = 80, 
              C_Score = 70,
              D_Score = 60;

    cout << "What is your user name without spaces? " << endl;
    cin >> username;

    cout << "What is the first grade? " << endl;
    cin >> grade1;
    cout << "What is the second grade? " << endl;
    cin >> grade2;
    cout << "What is the third grade? " << endl;
    cin >> grade3;
    cout << "What is the fourth grade? " << endl;
    cin >> grade4;
    cout << "What is the fifth grade? " << endl;
    cin >> grade5;
    cout << "What is the sixth grade? " << endl;
    cin >> grade6;
    cout << "What is the seventh grade? " << endl;
    cin >> grade7;
    cout << "What is the eighth grade? " << endl;
    cin >> grade8;
    cout << "What is the ninth grade? " << endl;
    cin >> grade9;
    cout << "What is the ninth grade? " << endl;
    cin >> grade10;


        if (  grade1 >= A_Score )
            letter1 = "A";
        else if ( grade1 >= B_Score )
            letter1 = "B";
        else if ( grade1 >= C_Score )
            letter1 = "C";
        else if ( grade1 >= D_Score )
            letter1 = "D";
        else if ( grade1 >= 0 )
            letter1 = "F";


        if (  grade2 >= A_Score )
            letter2 = "A";
        else if ( grade2 >= B_Score )
            letter2 = "B";
        else if ( grade2 >= C_Score )
            letter2 = "C";
        else if ( grade2 >= D_Score )
            letter2 = "D";
        else if ( grade2 >= 0 )
            letter2 = "F";


        if (  grade3 >= A_Score )
            letter3 = "A";
        else if ( grade3 >= B_Score )
            letter3 = "B";
        else if ( grade3 >= C_Score )
            letter3 = "C";
        else if ( grade3 >= D_Score )
            letter3 = "D";
        else if ( grade3 >= 0 )
            letter3 = "F";


        if (  grade4 >= A_Score )
            letter4 = "A";
        else if ( grade4 >= B_Score )
            letter4 = "B";
        else if ( grade4 >= C_Score )
            letter4 = "C";
        else if ( grade4 >= D_Score )
            letter4 = "D";
        else if ( grade4 >= 0 )
            letter4 = "F";


        if (  grade5 >= A_Score )
            letter5 = "A";
        else if ( grade5 >= B_Score )
            letter5 = "B";
        else if ( grade5 >= C_Score )
            letter5 = "C";
        else if ( grade5 >= D_Score )
            letter5 = "D";
        else if ( grade5 >= 0 )
            letter5 = "F";


        if (  grade6 >= A_Score )
            letter6 = "A";
        else if ( grade6 >= B_Score )
            letter6 = "B";
        else if ( grade6 >= C_Score )
            letter6 = "C";
        else if ( grade6 >= D_Score )
            letter6 = "D";
        else if ( grade6 >= 0 )
            letter6 = "F";


        if (  grade7 >= A_Score )
            letter7 = "A";
        else if ( grade7 >= B_Score )
            letter7 = "B";
        else if ( grade7 >= C_Score )
            letter7 = "C";
        else if ( grade7 >= D_Score )
            letter7 = "D";
        else if ( grade7 >= 0 )
            letter7 = "F";


        if (  grade8 >= A_Score )
            letter8 = "A";
        else if ( grade8 >= B_Score )
            letter8 = "B";
        else if ( grade8 >= C_Score )
            letter8 = "C";
        else if ( grade8 >= D_Score )
            letter8 = "D";
        else if ( grade8 >= 0 )
            letter8 = "F";


        if (  grade9 >= A_Score )
            letter9 = "A";
        else if ( grade9 >= B_Score )
            letter9 = "B";
        else if ( grade9 >= C_Score )
            letter9 = "C";
        else if ( grade9 >= D_Score )
            letter9 = "D";
        else if ( grade9 >= 0 )
            letter9 = "F";


        if (  grade10 >= A_Score )
            letter10 = "A";
        else if ( grade10 >= B_Score )
            letter10 = "B";
        else if ( grade10 >= C_Score )
            letter10 = "C";
        else if ( grade10 >= D_Score )
            letter10 = "D";
        else if ( grade10 >= 0 )
            letter10 = "F";


        if (  average >= A_Score )
            letteravg = "A";
        else if ( average >= B_Score )
            letteravg = "B";
        else if ( average >= C_Score )
            letteravg = "C";
        else if ( average >= D_Score )
            letteravg = "D";
        else if ( average >= 0 )
            letteravg = "F";

    cout << " Grade = " << grade1 << " = " << letter1 << endl;
    cout << " Grade = " << grade2 << " = " << letter2 << endl;
    cout << " Grade = " << grade3 << " = " << letter3 << endl;
    cout << " Grade = " << grade4 << " = " << letter4 << endl;
    cout << " Grade = " << grade5 << " = " << letter5 << endl;
    cout << " Grade = " << grade6 << " = " << letter6 << endl;
    cout << " Grade = " << grade7 << " = " << letter7 << endl;
    cout << " Grade = " << grade8 << " = " << letter8 << endl;
    cout << " Grade = " << grade9 << " = " << letter9 << endl;
    cout << " Grade = " << grade10 << " = " << letter10 << endl;
    cout << " Your average is  " << average << " = " << letteravg << endl;

    system("Pause");


return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about using a `struct Student` and have these values bundled there? Then have a `std::array<Student,10>`, and read in the values according a counting index? You didn't initialize any of your variables properly BTW.

Comment: _"I am getting error C4700, uninitialized local variable. Any tips on where I went wrong?"_ I'll just take a stab in the dark and suggest that you went wrong by not initializing a local variable...?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - what a gross leap of imagination.  How could you possibly come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 2):

```
double average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 ...
```

This is not doing what you think it is.

Initialising a variable to an expression that refers to other variables, the expression is immediately evaluated. The values of `grade1` etc *at that time* are used to set the initial value of `average`. It's not like a function with the result of the expression `average` changing over time as the values of `grade1` etc change.

Unfortunately, you're doing this long before providing any values into `grade1` etc, and this error is telling you that the variables were not even initialised so their values are *indeterminate*.

You should move the declaration of `average` down to a later position in the function, a position at which you actually have values with which to make the calculation.

Furthermore, incidentally, you should *really* be using arrays and loops here; you've repeated the majority of your program ten times for no good reason.

Here's how I'd write it (though I didn't include input validation / error checking, which you definitely should):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

const int A_Score = 90,
          B_Score = 80, 
          C_Score = 70,
          D_Score = 60;


char getLetterForGrade(unsigned int grade)
{
    if (grade >= A_Score)
        return 'A';
    else if (grade >= B_Score)
        return 'B';
    else if (grade >= C_Score)
        return 'C';
    else if (grade >= D_Score)
        return 'D';
    else
        return 'F';
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    unsigned int grades [N] = {};
    char         letters[N] = {};
    char         letterAvg  = 0;
    std::string  username;

    std::cout << "What is your user name without spaces? " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> username;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::cout << "What is grade #" << i << "? " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> grades[i];
        letters[i] = getLetterForGrade(grades[i]);
    }

    const double average = std::accumulate(std::begin(grades), std::end(grades), 0u) / N;
    letterAvg = getLetterForGrade(average);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::cout << " Grade: " << grades[i] << " = " << letters[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << " Your average is " << average << " = " << letterAvg << std::endl;
}
```

In fact, you don't even need the array `letters`, since their values can simply be calculated in that final loop.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the program executes from top to bottom within functions. Thus, you declared `grade1` through `grade10` without initializing them and then used those to calculate the average before even getting input. This is unlike languages such as VHDL where statement order generally doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You declare average to be initialized to the sum of 10 variables you haven't initialized yet.